# Issue with theme integration Magento 2

Tags: magento2

We are currently working on Magento 2 Community edition . We are stuck with front end integration.

We have created a custom theme inherited from Luma. But we are not able to add custom css/js files with default_head_blocks.xml file. Seems like default.xml is not getting overrided.  It would be really great if you can help as soon as possible since we are stuck for last 2 weeks.